# Rasbmc Network Installer Hangs on Second Reboot

Tags: raspbmc

Ok so I have an early model Raspberry Pi (512 model), with an Edimax supported WiFi card installed in it. I used the automatic installer on the Raspbmc website to setup the SD card (and dongle), downloaded and installed the filesystem - and then the Pi goes into a reboot.

Whilst rebooting, it comes up with this:

nit: Failed to spawn network-autoip main process: unable to execute: no such file or directory
nit: xmbc pre-start process (321) terminated with status 1
nit: console-setup pre-start process (245) terminated with status 1
nit: custom-network main process (585) terminated with status 1
nit: idmapd pre-start process (671) terminated with status 1
nit: gssd pre-start process (680) terminated with status 1

And then nothing. I tried rebooting, to which I just get the big R logo.

From what I've seen online this is a relatively common occurrence, but I can't find any solutions. Would appreciate any direction or thoughts.

Comment: I have same problem, and I can't find any response on the network. What did you do, finally? Re-install the system?

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Detach it from internet.  It's checking for updates constantly.  Then when it loads, go into settings and uncheck look for updates.